# Project turned grey, Cant Undo?

Tags: error

Yo, I was trying to roughly model a character in blender, when i click on something and everything went grey. its all mushy when i move the camera around, and i cant seem to Undo it. help?
i really have no idea what went wrong, im pretty new to blender.

[image: This is how it looks now, after i fucked up]

Comment: Try pressing Z, this should bring you into wireframe mode, then Z again. Does that help?

Comment: what the.. that fixed it xD. what did i do??

Comment: You changed the viewport [shading mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html#shading).

Comment: @Leander, you should post an answer!